# Web app initial load time

Tags: page-load-time

I am using a shared hosting plan at Bluehost to host a golf tournament live scoring mobile web app. I am caching everything I can on Cloudflare, and spent quite some time on overall optimization of the initial download & rendering times. There might be more I could do, but without question my single biggest issue is the initial call to my website: www.spanishpointscup.org. Sometimes this seems to be related to DNS lookup and other times related to Waiting(TTFB).

Below are 2 screen shot images of the network calls that show variations in accessing my index.html. Sometimes this initial file load can be even longer. Very rarely are any of the other files downloaded creating a long delay time, so my only focus now is the initial file load. I think that even if I had server side rendering, I would still have this issue.

Does anyone have specific recommendations that they are confident will help me? Switch to VPS or other host? Thank you.

[image: Initial file download good here.]

[image: Slower initial file download.]

Comment: If your DNS lookups are slow, switch DNS providers. If the TTFB is slow, your server side code is running slowly, optimize it or get more resources.

Comment: Bluehost uses NS1 which has good ratings on internet. My index.html is completely static, so it should only be a matter of accessing this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical when you use a shared server.

The DNS has nothing to do with the issue.  DNS has to do with the request not the response.  It is the Browser that must resolve the the domain name to an ip address.

The delay you are seeing is due to the server being busy and your page is sitting in a queue waiting behind other processes. Possibly you have a CPU grabbing neighbor on your shared server. Or Bluehost has some performance issues.

You will likely notice some image files take an excessively long time to transmit.  Which image is slow will appear to be random with each fresh (not in cache) page load.

### UPDATE

After further review I noticed the "wait" times are excessive.  Wait time is in green on your waterfall.  Notice how the transmit time (blue) is short.  This is the time it takes the server to retrieve the page from the disk and put it into the transmit buffer. 300-400 millisecond is excessive.

Find a new service provider.

Comment: Thx. I have been happy overall with Bluehost, including up time, tech support, and cost of shared hosting. I was thinking this was a fundamental limitation to shared hosting, but wanted some feedback before going to the trouble of switching.

Comment: When considering a new ISP run a page speed test like webpagetest.org on not only the ISP's web page but a client.  Generally an ISP has a free trial period.  Before setting up you web site,.load a test page with lots of images of various sizes  and look at the waterfall.  One of the best ISPs out there is AWS EC2 and they have a one year free trial.  A bit of a learning curve to use EC2, but it is good and as inexpensive as it gets.